# Read in HDF5 dataset as fast as possible

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, hdf5, h5py

**I need to read in a very large H5 file from disk to memory as fast as possible.**

I am currently attempting to read it in using multiple threads via the multiprocessing library, but I keep getting errors related to the fact that H5 files cannot be read in concurrently.

Here is a little snippet demonstrating the approach that I am taking:

```
import multiprocessing
import h5py
import numpy

f = h5py.File('/path/to/dataset.h5', 'r')

data = f['/Internal/Path/Dataset'] # this is just to get how big axis 0 is
dataset = numpy.zeros((300, 720, 1280)) # what to read the data into

def process_wrapper(frameCounter):
    dataset[frameCounter] = f['/Internal/Path/Dataset']

#init objects
cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cores)
jobs = []

#create jobs
frameCounter = 0
for frame in range(0, data.shape[0]): # iterate through axis 0 of data
    jobs.append( pool.apply_async(process_wrapper,([frameCounter])) )
    frameCounter += 1

#wait for all jobs to finish
for job in jobs:
    job.get()

#clean up
pool.close()
```

I am looking for either a workaround that will allow me to use multiple readers on the H5 file or a different approach that would still allow me to read it in faster. Thanks

Comment: http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/mpi.html - parallel HDF5 docs.